# Sending notifications on failing assertions for a simulation

Tags: gatling

**Background**:

Using Gatling version 3.9.5 (Open Source) for Java and running distributed load testing on K8s with two jobs:

- Running with no-reports to generate logs
- Running with reportsOnly with the logs generated in the first step.

Now, I'd like to send notifications on slack/teams for failed assertions so that we can have teams look at it.

I'd like recommendations on achieving this functionality.

FYI - I did some chatGPT and Bard searches as well but probably found some non-factual information, suggesting to write a Gatling custom listener and invoke it in the setup step which I couldn't find any documentation for.

Comment: I don't understand why did I earn a negative vote here, can someone explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the features you're trying to build (and many more) are available in Gatling Enterprise:

- [distributed tests](https://gatling.io/docs/enterprise/cloud/reference/user/simulations/#step-2-locations-configuration)
- [Slack and MS Teams notifications](https://gatling.io/docs/enterprise/cloud/reference/admin/notifications/)

I would not recommend building your own.

Comment: Got it, I am relatively new to Gatling and hadn't explored the "Enterprise" version yet. Thank you!